# DocuSign Envelopes API : listStatusChanges retrieve voided reason & date_time

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to retrieve the voided reason and the voided date time of an envelope with the listStatusChanges of the Envelope API with the PHP SDK.
As you can see, the envelope status is "voided" and the voided_reason returned is null but there should be a string.

```
DocuSign\eSign\Model\Envelope {#xxxxx ▼
  #container: array:79 [▼
    "access_control_list_base64" => null
    "allow_comments" => null
    "allow_markup" => "false"
    "allow_reassign" => null
    "allow_view_history" => null
    "any_signer" => null
    "asynchronous" => null
    "attachments_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/attachments"
    "authoritative_copy" => null
    "authoritative_copy_default" => null
    "auto_navigation" => "true"
    "brand_id" => null
    "brand_lock" => null
    "burn_default_tab_data" => null
    "certificate_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/documents/certificate"
    "completed_date_time" => null
    "copy_recipient_data" => null
    "created_date_time" => "2023-07-12T15:52:44.7830000Z"
    "custom_fields" => DocuSign\eSign\Model\CustomFields {#xxxxx ▶}
    "custom_fields_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/custom_fields"
    "declined_date_time" => null
    "deleted_date_time" => null
    "delivered_date_time" => null
    "disable_responsive_document" => null
    "document_base64" => null
    "documents_combined_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/documents/combined"
    "documents_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/documents"
    "email_blurb" => "Merci de bien vouloir signer le contrat."
    "email_settings" => null
    "email_subject" => "xxxxx"
    "enable_wet_sign" => null
    "enforce_signer_visibility" => null
    "envelope_attachments" => null
    "envelope_custom_metadata" => null
    "envelope_documents" => array:8 [▶]
    "envelope_id" => "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
    "envelope_id_stamping" => "true"
    "envelope_location" => "not_specified"
    "envelope_metadata" => null
    "envelope_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx"
    "expire_after" => "120"
    "expire_date_time" => null
    "expire_enabled" => "true"
    "external_envelope_id" => null
    "folders" => array:1 [▶]
    "has_comments" => null
    "has_form_data_changed" => null
    "has_wav_file" => null
    "holder" => null
    "initial_sent_date_time" => null
    "is21_cfr_part11" => null
    "is_dynamic_envelope" => null
    "is_signature_provider_envelope" => "false"
    "last_modified_date_time" => "2023-07-13T09:27:27.9270000Z"
    "location" => null
    "lock_information" => null
    "message_lock" => null
    "notification" => null
    "notification_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/notification"
    "power_form" => null
    "purge_completed_date" => null
    "purge_request_date" => null
    "purge_state" => "unpurged"
    "recipients" => DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients {#xxxxx ▶}
    "recipients_lock" => null
    "recipients_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/recipients"
    "sender" => DocuSign\eSign\Model\UserInfo {#17619 ▶}
    "sent_date_time" => "2023-07-12T15:52:54.5170000Z"
    "signer_can_sign_on_mobile" => null
    "signing_location" => "online"
    "status" => "voided"
    "status_changed_date_time" => "2023-07-13T09:27:27.9270000Z"
    "status_date_time" => null
    "templates_uri" => "/envelopes/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx/templates"
    "transaction_id" => null
    "use_disclosure" => null
    "voided_date_time" => null
    "voided_reason" => null
    "workflow" => null
  ]
}
```

I tried to add all the ["include" parameter values listed in the documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/) but it didn't change anything. All my voided envelope have a null "voided_reason".

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I just tried this and it worked ok, I used the PHP SDK. Are you using latest version of PHP SDK? can you share your PHP code that you run here?

Comment: @InbarGazit I found the issue. I used the ->setFromToStatus('Created') to list all my envelopes created in a month period. Is there a way to retrieve the voided reason with this parameter enable ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid no

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that you set:

```
setFromToStatus('Created')
```

Remove that settings and you'll get the voided reason in your response.

Envelopes in "created" status cannot be voided, thus this limitation.